# Multiple XMLs into powershell, extracting info, then using the info

Tags: xml, powershell

I am having an issue with importing multiple XMLs to Powershell, extracting the information I need and then using the information.  Here is the deal  I have imported my XML's fine the info is correct and gets outputted but I have no idea what else to do to export the information to a CSV or to just use the information to Updated an attribute in ARS (AD).

```
cls
$filePath = dir("c:\Users\*.xml")
foreach ($f in $filePath){
$xml = [Xml] (Get-Content $f)
$xml.myFields.Employee | Select-Object Acct.EmployeeId
}
```

The output I get is correct but if I were to put:

```
$test = $xml.myFields.Employee | Select-Object Acct.EmployeeId
```

And work with this I get a value of @{Acct.EmployeeID=matt} and I can not pipe it through Get-Qaduser and I can't export it to a csv because it just overrides everything and I get left with the very last XML documents information.  The same thing happens to me if I put the export-csv on the inside of the brackets or on the outside.

I understand this maybe a newbie question but I am just starting out and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
<my:myFields xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    <my:Employee>
        <my:Acct.Action>XXXX</my:Acct.Action>
        <my:Acct.Eff_date>XXXX</my:Acct.Eff_date>
        <my:Acct.E_last>XXXX</my:Acct.E_last>
        <my:Acct.E_first>XXXX</my:Acct.E_first>
        <my:Acct.E_init>XXXX</my:Acct.E_init>
        <my:Acct.E_title>XXXX</my:Acct.E_title>
        <my:Acct.E_dept>XXXX</my:Acct.E_dept>
        <my:Acct.E_phext>XXXX</my:Acct.E_phext>
        <my:Acct.Rep_phext></my:Acct.Rep_phext>
        <my:Acct.Same_last></my:Acct.Same_last>
        <my:Acct.Same_first></my:Acct.Same_first>
        <my:Acct.Action_tip></my:Acct.Action_tip>
        <my:Acct.Rep_display></my:Acct.Rep_display>
        <my:Acct.EmployeeID>XXXX</my:Acct.EmployeeID>
        <my:Acct.Email>XXXX</my:Acct.Email>
        <my:EmployeeContractor>
    </my:Employee>
```

Last Question (posted in the comments):

```
$users = Get-Content -Raw -Path "c:\Users\*.xml"
| ForEach-Object { ([xml] $_).myFields.Employee.'Acct.EmployeeID' } |   
export-csv c:\Users\mattheww\Desktop\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Or

```
$users = Get-Content -Raw -Path "c:\Users\*.xml"
| ForEach-Object { ([xml] $_).myFields.Employee.'Acct.EmployeeID' }
foreach ($user in $users) {
Get-qaduser -SamAccountName $user | select firstname}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Get-Content -Raw -Path c:\Users\*.xml | 
  ForEach-Object { ([xml] $_).myFields.Employee.'Acct.EmployeeID' }
```

This code also streamlines your approach:

- Instead of a `Get-ChildItem` (which `dir` is an alias for) / `Get-Content` combination, a single `Get-Content` call is sufficient; note the inclusion of `-Raw`, which ensures that each file is returned as a *single string* containing the entire contents.
- The strings containing the contents of the input file are sent through the pipeline, and processed one by one by the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet:

  - `([xml] $_)` simply casts the file content at hand to an XML document (`$_` (or `$PSItem`) is the automatic variable referring to the current pipeline input object).
  - `myFields.Employee.'Acct.EmployeeID'` then drills down into the XML document to extract the value of interest (which is implictly output).

    - Note the need for the surrounding quotes in `'Acct.EmployeeID'`, so as to distinguish between use of `.` to drill down into the hierarchy and accessing a property whose *name* happens to include `.`

To save the employee IDs in variable `$users` while also piping them to `Get-QADUser`:

```
Get-Content -Raw -Path c:\Users\*.xml | 
  ForEach-Object -ov users { ([xml] $_).myFields.Employee.'Acct.EmployeeID' } |
    ForEach-Object { Get-qaduser -SamAccountName $_ | Select-Object firstname }
```

Thanks to `-ov user` (short for: `-OutVariable user`), `$user` receives the array of all employee IDs created by the (first)  `ForEach-Object` call.

While you could pipe to `Export-Csv` instead in principle, it wouldn't make sense to do so with mere *strings*, because `Export-Csv` makes the properties of the input objects the column names, and type `[string]` has just a `.Length` property, so your CSV files would only contain the string *lengths*.

Thus, you can either

- use `Set-Content` / `Out-File` to write the strings as-is,
- or send the entire employee objects to `Export-Csv`, by simply omitting the `.'Acct.EmployeeId'` part:

```
Get-Content -Raw -Path c:\Users\*.xml | 
  ForEach-Object -ov users { ([xml] $_).myFields.Employee } | 
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation ~\Desktop\test.csv
```

Note that use of the pipeline with the `ForeEach-Object` *cmdlet* (or its built-in alias, `%`) generally makes for more elegant solutions than a `foreach` *loop* (though the latter construct is usually faster).

---

As for your code:

`Select-Object` returns  *custom objects* with an `Acct.EmployeeId` *property* that contains the value of interest:

- `@{Acct.EmployeeID=matt}` is what that object looks like in a *string* context.
- By contrast, when output to the *console*, PowerShell's helpful default formatting gave you what *looked* like just the *values* of interest, but the presence of *header* `Acct.EmployeeId` (underlined with `---`) is an indicator that *objects with a property named `Acct.EmployeeId`* were output.
- When in doubt about what types are being output, pipe to `... | Get-Member`.

`dir("c:\Users\*.xml")` happens to work, but suggests a misconception about PS syntax: You're using .NET method syntax, whereas PS cmdlets use *argument* syntax (as in traditional shells), so it's better to write the command as follows:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\Users\*.xml"
```

Or, relying on the fact that `-Path` is implicitly the first *positional* parameter, and that quoting this particular path is not necessary:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\Users\*.xml
```

You only need to quote string arguments (in argument mode) if they contain characters that have special meaning in PowerShell; a caveat is that there are different and more such characters when compared to `cmd.exe`

```
<space> " # & ' ( ) , ; < > @ ` { | }
```

You can quote via `"..."` (expandable string), `'...'` (string literal), or by quoting (escaping) individual chars. with `` ` `` (backtick; can also be used inside `"..."`); to embed a `'` inside `'...'`, use `''`.

Comment: I tried this by itself and received the entire XML in my console, was this what we were trying to achieve?  Also I should mention that my XML document looks like this (I have updated my original question with the XML format).  I should also mention I didn't create this XML.

Comment: Last question, to use this data after I save that statement into a $users variable.  do I just use another foreach statement like foreach ($user in $users) and go from there?  or can I just put export-csv at the end of your code? I am putting the code I was thinking about in my original question again.

Comment: My pleasure. Re your follow-up question: please see my latest update. I know it's not always easy, but please try to state all of your requirements up front next time. Sometimes, especially when multiple answers have already been given, it's better to post a follow-up question as a _new_ question.

Comment: I'd like to thank you @mklement0  You have honestly gone above and beyond.  I have finally gotten it to work and want to say thank you one last time.

Comment: @MatthewWander: I appreciate the kind feedback, and I'm glad to hear it worked for you.